# Как вычесть две переменные типа string? PHP

Tags: php

```
$query ="SELECT FIO, Stavka, YEAR(DataOfYstr), Dolgnosty.ID_dolgnosty FROM sotrudniki, Dolgnosty WHERE ID = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' AND sotrudniki.ID_dolgnosty = Dolgnosty.ID_dolgnosty";
    // выполняем запрос
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die("Ошибка " . mysql_error($link)); 
    //если в запросе более нуля строк
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); // получаем первую строку
        $fio = $row[0];
        $stavka = $row[1];
        $dataofystr = $row[2];
        $id_dolgnosty = $row[3];

        $today = date("Y");
        var_dump($today);
        var_dump($dataofystr);
        //settype($today , integer);



$today1 = intval($today);
            $stavka1 = intval($stavka);
            $raznica = $today1 - $stavka1;
var_dump($raznica);
```

вот что выдает: string(4) "2017" string(4) "1989" int(-1883)

Comment: это наглая ложь

Comment: `$a = intval("1987");$b = intval(date("Y"));`

Comment: Не работает, всё то же число

Comment: Потому что ты обманываешь и приводишь, видимо, явно не то, что конкретно вызывает такие данные

Comment: А, так вы про это. Хорошо, приведу конкретно свои переменные. Смотрите редатированный пост

Comment: иии как связаны `var_dump($dataofystr)` и `$stavka1 = intval($stavka);` ?

Comment: на случай если вдруг не понятно, выводите вы `$row[2]` а вычитаете `$row[1]`

Comment: Ну что сказать, на дворе ночь, за компьютером баба, это нормально, спасибо что указали на ошибку :)